# Changing from highlighting a cell to highlighting an entire row in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update a macro made by a former coworker. The original macro finds any forms with 'Help' in a report, changes it to 'HELP' then highlights the specific cell containing the word 'HELP' (these cells are all in the A column.) A team mate asked me if I could change it to highlight the entire row instead of just that cell and as someone new to VBA I'm having a heck of a time figuring it out.

The current code looks like this:

```
Public Sub DR_HelpReplace()
'Replace any instance of Help with HELP and highlight cell

    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ColorIndex = 22
    End With
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Replace what:="help", Replacement:="HELP", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

After searching around, I tried changing the .ColorIndex to '.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex' but that just throws an error.  Apologies if this is a really simple mistake, I'm learning as I go.

Comment: Any reason you're not using conditional formatting for the highlighting?

Comment: Probably easier to loop over the range to do this if you don't want to use CF.

Comment: It's entirely possible I've misunderstood the uses and limitations of CF, but from what I gathered it's worksheet specific right? This macro is part of a custom ribbon that my entire team uses, each week one of us handles formatting and double checking a discontinued report for the company so this ribbon was built to streamline that process and I need the macro to work at the push of a button rather than setting up a rule. Again, apologies if I'm wrong about how that works!

Answer (score 3):

Just loop the cells:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    If LCase$(cell.Value) = "help" Then
        cell.Value = "HELP"
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    End If
Next
```